# LiveData doesn't observe changes occurred from another view model instance?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a `AndroidViewModel` used in two `fragments` and contains a `LiveData` object like the following

```
public class CartViewModel<v extends CartCallback> extends BaseViewViewModel<v> {

    private RoomDb roomDb;
    private BaseApi api;
    private AppExecutors executors;
    private PrefsManger prefsManger;

    private LiveData<List<LineEntity>> lines;
    private LiveData<List<ImageEntity>> images;
    private MutableLiveData<CartInfo> cartInfo;

    private LiveData<Long> linesCount;


    public CartViewModel(Application application, RoomDb roomDb, BaseApi api, AppExecutors executors, PrefsManger prefsManger) {
        super(application);
        this.roomDb = roomDb;
        this.api = api;
        this.executors = executors;
        this.prefsManger = prefsManger;

        lines = roomDb.lineDao().getAllLines();
    }


    public LiveData<List<LineEntity>> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    public void saveOfflineLine(LineEntity entity) {
        executors.diskIO().execute(() -> roomDb.lineDao().save(entity));
    }
}
```

and at both fragments I initiate the view model like this

```
CartViewModel cartViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, cartFactory).get(CartViewModel.class);
    cartViewModel.attachView(this);
```

when I observe on lines liveData from one fragment and user `saveOfflineLine(entity)` from another on onChange doesn't trigger
but if observe and save from the same fragment(means the same instance from view model) `onChange` trigger successfully

Answer (score 1):

Pass in `getActivity()` instead of `this` as shown below so that view model is shared across the fragments

```
CartViewModel cartViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(),cartFactory).get(CartViewModel.class);
```

Comment: But, This Activity have many fragments that show and disappears so I need the lifeCycleOwner to be the fragment, not the Activity.